# How to round Quantity instances in brian2?

Tags: python, brian

I have this problem:

```
equilibrium_potential = my_func()  # outputs equilibrium_potential*mV
```

I want to check that `equilibrium_potential` is around `77*mV`. I've tried calling base python `round` on the `equilibrium_potential` which is of type `brian2.units.fundamentalunits.Quantity` so the interpreter threw an error. I also tried `np.round` from NumPy; the program didn't crash, but it did output `0*mV` which is also not what I want. Does anyone know how to round using Brian2?

I've looked at the [documentation](https://brian2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/brian2.units.fundamentalunits.Quantity.html?highlight=brian2.units.fundamentalunits.Quantity), but it doesn't seem to provide any useful steps towards a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`abs(equilibrium_potential/mV-77) < 0.1`

To do something within an equation if `equilibrium_potential` is outside the range, you need to wrap this code by `int` function. Like that:

```
int(abs(equilibrium_potential/mV-77) < 0.1)
```